# Battery charging indicator went crazy on my Samsung Duos S6802

Tags: charging

While I was playing a game, my cellphone warned me that my battery went too low. I plugged the charger but it was like it didn't work (charger indicator didn't show the bolt icon). After several efforts I found out that the battery was charging, simply the indicator didn't work. Unfortunately on my panic I had done a format (USB Storage) thinking that an installed app was causing this. However, this was not the case.

The battery charge indicator is now working half the times I am plugging it for charging. Upon going to the battery statistics, I observe a strange behavior: it shows it is almost (or half) -empty but the battery timer says that there is enough battery for 3 days while in another phone with similar battery and phone usage it shows full battery but 11h remaining time only.

How should I proceed?

Samsung S6802 - v.2.3.6 Gingerbread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game's creators did not take right precautions for the version of android I have and it ran into some issues. Unfortunately, it is not recoverable with format; the problem isn't obvious at first sight though.